# drawRect in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawrect

I have a simple example, custom UIView that draws a line with scale tick marks (0 - 8000). I have a testbutton when I click, the tick marks range change from (0-5000) and I force setNeedsDisplay to redraw the new labels for tick marks. I do hit the new values in drawrect, but it never redraws the new labels, it only draws new labels on first launch. Any clue? Here is the code.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect  //TESTTTTTTTTT
{
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  if(test){
     // [self setClearsContextBeforeDrawing: YES];
    high1=5000;
    high2 = 1000;
}


high1 = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MaxScale1"] doubleValue];
high2 = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MaxScale2"] doubleValue];

CGFloat x1,x2,x3;
CGFloat y1top, y2top,y3top;
CGFloat y1bot, y2bot,y3bot;
x1=63;
x2=76;
x3 = x1-5;
float ht = 96;

y1top = y2top = y3top= 114;
y1bot = y2bot= y3bot = y1top+ht;

////Gauge1 /////
float w1 = 308; //gaugeView1.size.width;
float x1Start=5;
float y1 = 90;
float div1= w1/4.0;
CGContextMoveToPoint(context,x1Start, y1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1Start, y1+5);
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
CGRect labrect = CGRectMake(x1Start-2,y1+5, 18, 7);
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",0] drawInRect:labrect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:7.5]];

CGContextMoveToPoint(context,x1Start+div1, y1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1Start+div1, y1+5);
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
labrect = CGRectMake(x1Start+div1-9,y1+5, 18, 7);
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(0.25*high1)] drawInRect:labrect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:7.5]];

CGContextMoveToPoint(context,x1Start+2*div1, y1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1Start+2*div1, y1+5);
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
labrect = CGRectMake(x1Start+2*div1-9,y1+5, 18, 7);
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(0.5*high1)] drawInRect:labrect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:7.5]];

CGContextMoveToPoint(context,x1Start+3*div1, y1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1Start+3*div1, y1+5);
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
labrect = CGRectMake(x1Start+3*div1-9,y1+5, 18, 7);
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(0.75*high1)] drawInRect:labrect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:7.5]];

CGContextMoveToPoint(context,x1Start+4*div1, y1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1Start+4*div1, y1+5);
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
labrect = CGRectMake(x1Start+4*div1-9,y1+5, 18, 7);
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(high1)] drawInRect:labrect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:7.5]];

//  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
 // CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
 CGContextStrokePath(context);


  }
```

Comment: What do you mean "I do hit the new values in drawrect"?  You are setting a breakpoint in drawrect?  Or doing an NSLog of the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a CGContextBeginPath to go along with your CGContextStrokePath.

Each time you draw you should start with CGContextBeginPath(context); and end with CGContextStrokePath(context);

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect  //TESTTTTTTTTT
{
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  if(test){
     // [self setClearsContextBeforeDrawing: YES];
    high1 = 5000;
    high2 = 1000;
  }


  high1 = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MaxScale1"] doubleValue];
  high2 = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MaxScale2"] doubleValue];

  CGFloat x1 ,x2, x3;
  CGFloat y1top, y2top, y3top;
  CGFloat y1bot, y2bot, y3bot;
  x1 = 63;
  x2 = 76;
  x3 = x1 - 5;
  float ht = 96;

  y1top = y2top = y3top= 114;
  y1bot = y2bot= y3bot = y1top + ht;

////Gauge1 /////
  float w1 = 308; //gaugeView1.size.width;
  float x1Start = 5;
  float y1 = 90;
  float div1= w1 / 4.0;

  CGContextBeginPath(context);
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x1Start, y1);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1Start, y1 + 5);
  [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
  CGRect labrect = CGRectMake(x1Start - 2, y1 + 5, 18, 7);
  [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 0] drawInRect:labrect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:7.5]];

  CGContextMoveToPoint(context ,x1Start + div1, y1);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1Start + div1, y1 + 5);
  [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
  labrect = CGRectMake(x1Start + div1 - 9,y1 + 5, 18, 7);
  [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(0.25 * high1)] drawInRect:labrect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:7.5]];

  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x1Start + 2 * div1, y1);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1Start + 2 * div1, y1 + 5);
  [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
  labrect = CGRectMake(x1Start + 2 * div1 - 9, y1 + 5, 18, 7);
  [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(0.5*high1)] drawInRect:labrect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:7.5]];

  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x1Start + 3 * div1, y1);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1Start + 3 * div1, y1 + 5);
  [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
  labrect = CGRectMake(x1Start + 3 * div1 - 9, y1 + 5, 18, 7);
  [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(0.75*high1)] drawInRect:labrect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:7.5]];

  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x1Start + 4 * div1, y1);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1Start + 4 * div1, y1 + 5);
  [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
  labrect = CGRectMake(x1Start + 4 * div1 - 9, y1 + 5, 18, 7);
  [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(high1)] drawInRect:labrect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:7.5]];

  CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: Oh, did you leave the CGContextBeginPath out of the code you copied into your answer above?

Comment: Because its not there.  And it needs to be there.

Comment: CGContextBeginPath(context); Which part of this line isn't showing in the code?